# Recreate AWS default subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet

I accidentally deleted all the default subnets in aws，I want to recreate  default subnets。I make CLI command: "aws ec2 create-default-subnet --availability-zone us-west-2a"
，but always get the error message
"An error occurred (DefaultSubnetAlreadyExistsInAvailabilityZone) when calling the CreateDefaultSubnet operation: 'subnet-015c449cab525d947' is already the default subnet in us-west-2d."
how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the problem? The error says `DefaultSubnetAlreadyExistsInAvailabilityZone` You may *think* that it doesn't... but if AWS thinks that it does - AWS opinion prevails!

Comment: Reconfirm your AZ in which you have deleted your default subnet, there might be chance you are creating default subnet in some other AZ

Comment: Also as per docs there can be only ` one default subnet per Availability Zone.`

Comment: @Jatin Mehrotra   I get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one default subnet can exist in each availability zone, seems you already have yours on us-west-2a, login to you AWS account search for VPC > Subnets and delete what you have there, then you can re-create it with this command:
ws ec2 create-default-subnet --availability-zone us-west-2a

check AWS document fore more info:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recreate-default-vpc/

Answer (score 1):

To create default subnets, you need to use AWS CLI. Through AWS console you cannot create default subnets.
Steps to create default subnet through AWS CLI:

1. Download and install AWS CLI, if not present.
2. Download Access keys of your AWS account(Click on account name and go to security credentials).
3. Open cmd
4. Write the command "aws configure".
5. Enter all the credentials(Security credentials from the downloaded csv file).
6. run the command "aws ec2 create-default-subnet --availability-zone us-east-2a"
   Write the region where you want to create default subnet instead of "us-east-2a"
7. open aws account to view subnets